# Get the XML content with AFNetworking library

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xml, afnetworking

now i would like use AFNetworking library to get XML content, so I use this code

```
AFXMLRequestOperation *operation = [AFXMLRequestOperation XMLParserRequestOperationWithRequest:request 
success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSXMLParser *XMLParser) 
{
    XMLParser.delegate = self;
    [XMLParser parse];
} 
failure:nil];
[operation start];
```

my question is to know if there is any way to get the content of the xml response ( i want to print the xml content with NSLog )

thanks in advance

Comment: If you'd like to receive a fully instantiated xml document check out this request operation subclass I created https://github.com/shawnwall/AFGXMLRequestOperation

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The raw data from the request is always available in the `responseData` property of the operation class. Here is how you would show it with `NSLog`:

```
__block AFXMLRequestOperation *operation = [AFXMLRequestOperation XMLParserRequestOperationWithRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://legalindexes.indoff.com/sitemap.xml"]] success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSXMLParser *XMLParser) {
    NSLog(@"Parser: %@", XMLParser);
    NSLog(@"Raw XML Data: %@", [[NSString alloc] initWithData:operation.responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
} failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, NSXMLParser *XMLParser) {
    NSLog(@"Failure!");
}];

[operation start];
```

That said, the standard `AFXMLRequestOperation` class uses `NSXMLParser` which is painful to use. If your payload isn't too big and performance isn't an issue, I suggest you use Mattt's new [AFKissXMLRequestOperation](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFKissXMLRequestOperation) class which will do the parsing for you and expose a friendlier [NSXMLDocument](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSXMLDocument_Class/Reference/Reference.html) compatible object:

```
__block AFKissXMLRequestOperation *operation = [AFKissXMLRequestOperation XMLDocumentRequestOperationWithRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://legalindexes.indoff.com/sitemap.xml"]] success:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, DDXMLDocument *XMLDocument) {
    NSLog(@"XMLDocument: %@", XMLDocument);
    NSLog(@"Raw XML Data: %@", [[NSString alloc] initWithData:operation.responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]);
} failure:^(NSURLRequest *request, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, DDXMLDocument *XMLDocument) {
    NSLog(@"Failure!");
}];

[operation start];
```

Comment: This is the better answer.

Answer (score 2):

I believe AFXMLRequestOperation is SAX Operation. I.e., the xml response are not received in one bunch (it keeps receiving until its done).

You can print the complete data received by printing `string`

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string
```

or appending string to a ivar and print it on `parserDidEndDocument`

```
- (void) parserDidEndDocument: (NSXMLParser *)parser
```

If you are trying to test the api to see the return. I use this method

```
[[AFHTTPClient sharedClient] postPath:url
                              parameters:nil 
                                 success:^( AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation , id responseObject ) {
                                     NSLog(@"responseobject: %@", [responseObject description]);
                                     }
                                     failure:^( AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation , NSError *error ){
                                        NSLog(@"Handle failure for me");
                                     }
                                     ]];
```