# To understand the AFNetworking ios library AFXMLRequestOperation

Tags: ios, afnetworking

Hi I am new to AFNetworking library and am integrating it for first time in my iPAD app. However I am having hard time finding a working example for reference.

I found the following solution by rckoenes here [AFNetworking POST and get Data back](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11863817/afnetworking-post-and-get-data-back). However I am hard time implementing it. Since that answer is already marked as correct. I am assuming the library as changed since that time and the example might not be relevant.

Any help with a working example reference is highly appreciated.

```
NSURLRequest *request =  [wsu generateURLRequest:getFavAPI method : @"GET" arguments:nil eventName:USER_FAVS_SUCCESS_NOTIF contentType:nil];
NSLog(@"Request %@", request.description);
AFXMLRequestOperation *favOpertion = [[AFXMLRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];
//favOpertion.responseXMLParser = [NSXMLParser initialize]; // error: setting the readOnly property.
[favOpertion setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *favOpertion, id responseObject) {
NSLog(@"Response: %@",[favOpertion responseString]); // Never reached here
} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *favOpertion, NSError *error) {
NSLog(@"Error: %@",[favOpertion error]);   // never reached here
}];
```

The code prints the request desc as valid: http://[server name]/favorites/folders/user/[uid]>

Answer (score 0):

Here is an [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10996986/get-the-xml-content-with-afnetworking-library) of the default SAX style parsing. There are some other XML request operations people have made that give you an actual XML document:

1. [AFKissXMLRequestOperation](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFKissXMLRequestOperation)
2. [AFGXMLRequestOperation](https://github.com/shawnwall/AFGXMLRequestOperation)